# Install dotnet Core on Raspbian 8

Tags: raspbian, software-compilation

I have Raspberry Pi 2 with latest Debian/Raspbian 8 OS.

How can I can compile/build run latest dotnet core on this ARM based OS?

I have tried install from official link: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#debian
but it seems that install script supports only x86 architecture. Can I easy make my own build of dotnet binary based on their git code which will work on my Raspbian? I am aware of Windows 10 for IoT which supports dotnet native, but I need this on Raspbian.

Comment: See also: [Is it possible to run .NET Core on Raspberry PI?
(SO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907857/is-it-possible-to-run-net-core-on-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score 2):

as today, there is no way to install dotnet core on ARM. See [Problem install .Net Core on Raspberry Pi Model B](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/140)
The [roadmap dated the ARM32/64 Support for a release in Q4 2016 / Q1 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/15/net-core-roadmap/). So there is the hope that dotnet core soon will run on Raspberry .